# Visualization of formation of cirrus vertebratus?

Tags: meteorology, wind, clouds, aerosol

I am trying to understand how Cirrus Vertebratus are formed.

My book and many web pages simply say "waves orthogonally to the initial cloud formation direction, in fitting conditions, forming clouds in up movement and no clouds in down movement"

So is the initial cloud moved from its starting position and leaves trails, or, is wind brushing through it, then how can the trails be on both sides of the initial cloud? Why are the trails left and right occuring only next to the cloud?
searching for an animation or something, I cant find videos online that "simulate"/visualize it. How do the waves happen? Is it light hot air brushing above dense colder air, or, the other way around, I've read both in my book.

Do you have any source that explains it more thouroughly?

Please excuse me if I use any terms wrongly, I am just trying to learn about it, and I am new, you need to start somewhere. Thank you in case any answers happen!

[image]